# Using Yahoo Pipes to remove a table

Tags: html, joomla, rss, html-table, yahoo-pipes

I'm importing RSS Newsfeeds using Yahoo Pipes and it works really well. My problem is that it sometimes imports Social Bookmarks. However these are encapsulated in a table. My question then is how to remove a table (thus removing the links it contains - the Social Bookmarks) using Yahoo Pipes?

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround I use: Just hide the table, div with social bookmarks. In your CSS:

```
div#bookmarks, table#bookmarks2{display:none;visibility:hidden;}
```